# When does a new __LINE__ start?

Tags: c++, macros, newline, c-preprocessor

I do not understand the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define FOO std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \
                      << __LINE__ << '\n';
int main()
{
    FOO

    std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \
              << __LINE__ << '\n';
}
```

The first output is `7` and `7`, indicating that the expansion of `FOO` is a single logical line, but the second output is `9` and `10`, indicating two distinct logical lines. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
1:  #include <iostream>
2: 
3:  #define FOO std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \
4:                        << __LINE__ << '\n';
5:  int main()
6:  {
7:      FOO // the first two __LINE__s come from here, that's one line of code
8: 
9:      std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \ // 3rd __LINE__ comes from here
10:              << __LINE__ << '\n'; // 4th __LINE__ comes from here
11: }
```

`__LINE__` expands to physical lines, not logical lines:

> The *line number* of the current source line is one greater than the number of new-line characters read or introduced in translation phase 1 (2.2) while processing the source file to the current token.

While the lines ended by `\` are concatenated in translation phase 2.

The other only logical implementation would be to print 3 and 4 for the invocation of FOO, but that seems not very useful.

You can also look at this the following way: `__LINE__` is not any different from any other macro. It's just updated automatically by the compiler at the beginning of every line. So the code is kind of interpreted this way:

```
#include <iostream>

#define __LINE__ 3
#define FOO std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \
                      << __LINE__ << '\n';
int main()
{
#define __LINE__ 7
    FOO

#define __LINE__ 9
    std::cout << __LINE__ << ' ' \ // Yeah, you're right
#define __LINE__ 10
             << __LINE__ << '\n';
}
```

This is not valid code, but it demonstrates how the things work. Apply the usual macro expansion rules and you'll get the output you've got.

Comment: And this is guaranteed by the standard? That would be great! I have some quite large macros containing multiple `__LINE__` tokens, and I would really like to split them up with backslashes, yet they must yield the same line when expanded.

Comment: Also note that when a macro containing linebreaks is expanded, the expanded macro does not contain linebreaks. The linebreak is escaped in the macro *definition*, so the "actual macro" doesn't have it. It's sort of the opposite of putting `\n` in a string. So you can pretty much just think of `__LINE__` as being replaced after other macro replacement.

Answer (score 2):

cause one you define in `#define` statement which always evaluated as one line. However, the second case is really two lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Because `#define` expansion contains hackery to make sure `__LINE__` is the one where the macro is "invoked". Otherwise a lot of error messages would make no sense to the user.

Comment: It's not hackery. It behaves like any other macro that you `#define` before the expansion of `FOO` and use inside `FOO`. The only special thing with `__LINE__` is that it's automatically updated at the beginning of every line.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution of Foo requires evaluation of the predefined directive _ _LINE _ _ . This as I understand is because, there is no second preprocessing pass to evaluate _ _LINE _ _  .

Hence the _ _LINE _ _  is evaluated based on the line on which Foo is being expaned which is Line 7.

The usage of _ _LINE _ _  in the subsequent line in your code is really evaluated during the preprocessing phase based on the exact line number it appears in the source code in the translation unit.